# Defining a Property Attribute

Tags: c#, attributes, propertygrid

In the following picture what is the attribute that I should set if I want to hard code the string it shows for that type of class?

[image]

In the same way I can hardcode the attribute in the red circle by:

> ```
>  [DisplayName("OriginalJoint2")]
> ```

What would be the equivalent for the yellow highlighted property?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to show a particular string in the "value" column of the property grid?

For this, you will need to implement a TypeConverter. See [Introduction to the TypeConverter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6390/Introduction-to-the-TypeConverter).

Comment: I do not want to use a type converter, I am attempting to do this generically so that the object itself contains the information being displayed.

Comment: Not possible. Use can return a hard-coded string from your TypeConverter.ConvertTo method.